# Trying to print zip column from the database using rest api

Tags: django

Error saying that too many values to unpack (expected 2).

views.py

```
@api_view(["GET"])        
def zipcodes(request):
   tasks= ZipCodes.objects.get('zip')
   if request.method == "GET":
      serializer = TaskSerializer(tasks, many=True)
      return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: `tasks= ZipCodes.objects.get('zip')` makes not much sense, since it should have a condition.

Comment: The **`get()`** method should be as `.get(field_name='zip')` syntax

Comment: Furthermore these are not tasks, so using a `TaskSerializer` is a bit *odd*.

Comment: Can you provide the best example?@WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 0):

when you want to multiple data don't use `get()` method
you can use following thing over there.

```
tasks = ZipCodes.objects.all().value('zip') 
if tasks.exists(): # to check query set is not empty
     serializer = TaskSerializer(tasks, many=True)
     return Response(serializer.data)  
# be careful it will return dict querySet like {'zip':value}
else:
     pass
     #return 404 if not any zip-code found.
```

if you want list, user `values_list`

```
tasks = ZipCodes.objects.values_list('zip',flat=True)
#it will querySet like [val1,val2,val3,...]
```